# Check if object is already in list (Python)

Tags: python

I have tried searching online for this, but unfortunately have not been able to come up with a solution so far, so I was hoping someone might be able to help me. My basic question is how can I check whether an object is already in a list?

I am currently working on a Rubik's Cube solver, and have created a class called `MyCube`, where each object has 4 properties:

```
def __init__(self, cp=None, co=None, ep=None, eo=None):
```

There are a number of methods for changing the properties, and I have also created methods for `__eq__` and `__ne__` as follows:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    if type(other) is type(self):
        return self.__dict__ == other.__dict__
    return False

def __ne__(self, other):
    return not self.__eq__(other)
```

I have a list of cubes `MyMoveCube = [MyCube() for i in range(18)]` and each cube goes through various different transformations. I then have another cube `MyNewCube` and I want to check whether it is already in `MyMoveCube` and if not to add it to the list.

I have tried the following, but I find that this gets very slow very quickly as the size of `MyMoveCube` increases:

```
for current_move in MyMoveCube:
    if current_move == MyNewCube:
        break
    MyMoveCube.append(MyNewCube)
```

My question is, is there a better way to do this without looping through it each time?

Comment: Why not simply use `if MyNewCube in MyMoveCube:...`? This will first check the identity and then will call `__eq__` if required.

Comment: Sets are great for non-repeating data which you check for membership a lot, e.g., if x in y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do something if `MyNewCube` is already in `MyMoveCube`,

```
if MyNewCube in MyMoveCube:
    do_whatever()
```

or if you want to do something if it isn't,

```
if MyNewCube not in MyMoveCube:
    do_whatever()
```

(I initially didn't see the part about running into speed problems; this answer just demonstrates `in` syntax. Testing lists for containment is horribly slow; for efficiency, see the other answer.)

Comment: I have tried using this, but it doesn't appear to work. It doesn't ever seem to think that there is an equality there unfortunately.

Comment: @GemmaDown: Then you've done something else wrong. Your `__eq__` and `__ne__` methods look like they should work.

Comment: Thanks for this - I think there must have been something else happening as this method is now working! Very glad to know that this will work too.

Answer (score 1):

> "but I find that this gets very slow very quickly as the size of MyMoveCube increases"

You will want to look into using a set to store your `MyCube` instances.

```
MyMoveCube = set([MyCube() for i in range(18)])
```

Hashing an object and checking whether it's in a `set` is a very efficient operation - `O(1)` in the average case compared to `O(n)` in the average case for a list.

You can still use the same `in` operators with a set, with much faster lookup:

```
if MyNewCube in MyMoveCube:
    # in cube
```

**EDIT:**

If you need to keep track of the order of the items in the set, you could possibly use a `set` AND a `list`. The list for tracking the order and the set for testing membership.

Comment: Thank you very much for this as well! Unfortunately I needed to keep the order of the cubes that I had for specific reference, so I wouldn't have been able to use a set in this instance, but this looks really useful, and is something I will certainly use elsewhere.

Comment: @GemmaDown why not use a list for keeping track of the order, and a set for when you want to test membership? You get the best of both worlds.

Comment: @GemmaDown: You can keep a set *and* a list, using the set to test for containment efficiently and using the list to track order. Alternatively, depending on how much control you need over the element order, [collections.OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) might do the job.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I will look into doing that.